# Problem with trigger in OntTriggerEnter2D in unity

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision, collider

[image: second object][image: first object]I have a two objects, both of them have : rigidbody2D of type dynamic, collider2D set to trigger, same layer, same Z position. But they do not collider with each other. One of them has a simple script attached, which contains function OnTriggerEnter2D, which just debug.log some message. As you can guess the console doesn't print the message. No errors tho. Please help! I've also tried to restart unity, even the PC - doesn't work as well.
function :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("DUOA");
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code and the gameobject components

Comment: Ok i did an edit to my post

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Collision action matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html), you will not receive a trigger call from two **dynamic** Rigidbodies that **both** have a **trigger** collider component.

Change one of the Rigidbody types to `Kinematic`, which should resolve your issue.

Comment: I found an issue... I changed edge collider to polygon collider, and now everything works